# how to change div style which is in master page from content page code behind file

Tags: master-pages, content-pages

I want to include that style class from external css file into content page code behind file. css file name is screen.css and it is having   `.bodydefault` class so how to access that css class from code behind?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question but what are trying to do with the class in the code behind?

If you have linked the screen.css file in the master page you can set the class of an element in the code behind using the following...

```
LinkButton1.CssClass = "bodydefault";
```

You can remove it using the following...

```
 LinkButton1.CssClass = null;
 LinkButton1.Attributes["class"] = null;
```